# SUSE 12 setting up virtual network interface

Tags: networking, interface, sles

I'm struggling to setup virtual eth interface on Suse 12

When I run:

```
ipconfig eth0:1 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Output from ifconfig is as expected:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:02:03:04:05
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.24.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:02:03:04:05
          inet addr:10.0.0.2  Bcast:10.0.24.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

However this setup is not persistent. When the system is restarted I can no longer see eth0:1

I tried adding the IPADDR1='10.0.0.2/24' to the /etc/sysconfig/network/if-eth0 config file and that seems to be working fine BUT I cannot see eth0:1 in the ifconfig output ?

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search I have found the answer:
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/networking/alias.txt

Looks like virtual/alias interfaces are deprecated and should be avoided and one should rather add multiple IP addresses directly to eth0